# sed "invalid command code W"

Tags: terminal

I am trying to prepend text to the begging/header of a set of .vtt text files with `sed` in a loop. I'm not replacing any text, only adding text.

I need some line breaks in the text.

The text should read:

WEBVTT
Kind: captions
Language: eng
File Creation Date: 2023-08

Here is what I am trying:

```
for file in *.vtt ; do 
sed -i '' 'WEBVTT/nKind: captions/nLanguage: eng/nFile Creation Date: 2023-08' "$file"
done
```

give me the error:
`sed: 1: 'WEBVTT/nKind: captions/ ...': invalid command code W`

I'm not sure why. I tried switching double/single quotes, but that didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to replace

Comment: @mmmmmm I'm not replacing anything, only attempting to add text to the begging/header of the file.

Comment: `W` is not a `sed` command. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: Do you understand that the basic structure of a `sed` command is `<operation><parameters>`? So the first character is a letter that indicates which operation to perform? The letter for adding to the file is `a`, and the parameter is separated by `\\ `

Comment: And if you want newlines, that's `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99350/how-to-insert-text-before-the-first-line-of-a-file Follow the instructions for non-GNU sed.